# The form of the cursor in vim in konsole in kde with tmux

Tags: vim, kde, tmux, konsole

I use KDE and for `vim` in Konsole, I have such commands in my `.vimrc`:

```
" Konsole
" solid underscore
let &t_SI = "\033]50;CursorShape=2\007"
" solid block
let &t_EI = "\033]50;CursorShape=0\007"
```

But it does not work when I use `tmux`. Why is that and what can I do to get this to work?

Comment: Do you need to simulate `vim` in `tmux`?

Comment: I do not understand your question. I use kde and konsole as a terminal emulator. I'm learning tmux just now. But cursor changing in vim (like in gvim) doesn't work when using tmux. (It works in konsole without using tmux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [my vim config](https://github.com/gastropoda/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/config/xterm_cursor.vim#L18-L26):

> tmux will only forward escape sequences to the terminal if surrounded by a
>   DCS sequence ([see](http://bit.ly/zImrzb))

So when my config detects that vim is running in tmux (`if exists('$TMUX')`) it will surround every escape sequence with `"\ePtmux;\e"` and `"\e\\"`

My escape sequences are xterm specific, but I guess you need to perform a similar trick for Konsole.

**N.b.:** `"\e"` is the same as `"\033"`

Your case would look like (sorry, untested):

```
" Konsole
" solid underscore
let &t_SI = "\033]50;CursorShape=2\007"
" solid block
let &t_EI = "\033]50;CursorShape=0\007"

if exists('$TMUX')
  let &t_SI = "\ePtmux;\e" . &t_SI . "\e\\"
  let &t_EI = "\ePtmux;\e" . &t_EI . "\e\\"
endif
```